# Resizing Subview by User by Dragging Vertical Line

Tags: swift, macos, user-interface

I try to find out if there is a chance to let the user resize a subview within an window by dragging a vertical line. The line is the `NSBox`object taken from the interface builder library. Both subviews (`tableview`and `textview`) should resize itself in the horizontal direction by dragging the line during runtime.

Any hints? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please forgive me if I have miss understood your question as it seems very basic and I feel I’m missing something! Your request can easily be achieved through Storyboard Interface Builder, in your Object Library search both Vertical Split View and Horizontal Split View, these are great tools to allow the user to increase or decrease split view requirements. You can drop your desired views into either! And auto sizing will be maintained during user endeavours, alternatively Stack Views can maintain similar effects.